# JSON-RPC for java library

Tags: java, json, post, json-rpc

I want to send datas from my Java program to a `Tine2.0` server. I have found a solution called `JSON-RPC for Java`, working on the Post http method.

I have already created a class doing a Post request to a test page of the server, this is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EnvoiEnBaseViaURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String tacheSent = URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8"); //args[0] = "tache a envoyer"
        String noteSent = URLEncoder.encode(args[1], "UTF-8"); //args[1] = "note a envoyer"
        String dossier = URLEncoder.encode(args[2], "UTF-8"); //args[2] = "dossier a envoyer"
        String context = URLEncoder.encode(args[3], "UTF-8"); //args[3] = "contexte a envoyer"
        String iD = URLEncoder.encode(args[4], "UTF-8");
        String pass = URLEncoder.encode(args[5], "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(args[6]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                     connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("TacheEnvoyee=" + tacheSent + "&NoteEnvoyee=" + noteSent + "&Dossier=" + dossier + "&Contexte=" + context + "&Identifiant=" + iD + "&Password=" + pass);
        out.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
        }
    in.close();
    }
}
```

It works, I successfully send datas to this page and it returns me what I have sent. But now I work with the Tine2.0 server, I have to use authentication to connect.

I have tried to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j, I have dowloaded the ZIP file but I dont know what am I supposed to do with, Where I have to send it...(the tutorial don't explain it at all...) At the moment, the `User`on the `public Interface UserService`doesn't exist, etc...

I think I can do what I want to just with

```
JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(
new URL("http://example.com/UserService.json"));

User user = client.invoke("createUser", new Object[] { "bob", "the builder" }, User.class);
```

But Java, obviously, as said previously, don't recognize `JsonRpcHttpClient` or `User`..

If anyone already worked with JSON-RPC and and can explain me what am I supposed to do, maybe install or add to the `Java Build Path`?

I hope i'm enough concise, don't hesitate to ask informations is some are missing.

Thank you.